# Why is a NullPointerException being thrown?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have the following program that scans a 2-dimensional matrix and checks for the position of 0s in rows and columns and make the entire row and column(rows and columns where 0 exists) , 0s in the matrix.

```
public static int[][] makeMatZero(int[][] matrix){
    Boolean[] row = new Boolean[matrix.length];
    Boolean[] col = new Boolean[matrix[0].length];

    for(int i = 0;i< matrix.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j< matrix[0].length;j++){
            if(mat[i][j]==0){
                row[i]=true;
                col[j]=true;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0;i<row.length;i++){
        if(row[i]){
            removeRow(i,mat);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<col.length;i++){
        if(col[i]){
            removeCol(i,mat);
        }
    }
    return matrix;


}


public static void removeRow(int row, int[][] mat){
    for(int j  = 0;j<mat[0].length;j++){
        mat[row][j]=0;  

    }
}
public static void removeCol(int col, int[][] mat){
    for(int j  = 0;j<mat.length;j++){
        mat[j][col]=0;  

    }
}
```

I get a nullPointerException in the line if(row[i]) and if i comment it out, i get an exception in if(col[i]). I tried debugging and printed out the values of i and row.length/col.length. The value of i never crosses row.length/col.length, but i still get a nullPointerException. Any help in letting me know what the mistake is much appreciated.

P.S : I am trying to solve few questions in the book "Cracking the coding Interview" by Gayle Laakmann McDowell and the above mentioned is one of the questions in the Chapter Arrays and Strings. The above solution too is given in the book

Comment: @thegauravmahawar Thank you. I needed this. It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a "small" `boolean`, not the `Boolean` class as type of your arrays, so all fields will be initialized with `false` instead of `null` (the latter leading to your `NullPointerException`).

Additional explanation: `Boolean` is a class, so the compiler performs so-called *autoboxing* for a line like this:

```
Boolean b = null;
if (b)
```

becomes

```
Boolean b = null;
if (b.booleanValue())
```

Here it is obvious that calling `.booleanValue()` on `null` is not a good idea.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I should have put more efforts before posting my question. Will try to put my 100% next time.

Comment: autoboxing is evil avoid it like the pest

Comment: @N_B You're welcome. Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: @ketrox fully agree.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Yes, i will definitely accept it. Not able to accept it now due to the time restriction.